# Using column/field names with parentheses in R

Tags: r

I am using R version 3.0.2 on Windows 7.

I load a CSV table into R and some of the column names have parentheses such as P(A) or P(A|B).  If I try

```
 whatever<- read.csv("C:/dir/name.csv", header=TRUE);
 hist(whatever$P(A|B));
```

I get the error message

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "hist(whatever$P(A|B"
```

Is it possible, in R, to use column names with parentheses or must I change the column names to alphanumeric?

Comment: Usually you can escape column names so that they can contain stuff like spaces and special characters by using the backtick (`)

Comment: Where the special characters actually preserved with the way you claim to have used `read.csv`? If you do have such characters, try using backticks (`) around the `P(A|B)`

Comment: Have tried using quotes? `hist(whatever$"P(A|B)")`

Comment: You need to add `check.names = FALSE`; otherwise, R will not let you have those column names like P(A|B)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read.csv()` will convert the special characters to '.' so the column 'P(A|B)' will be `whatever$P.A.B.`.

However, as @Floo0 pointed out, if you can have column names like 'P(A|B)' which are accessed by `whatever$"P(A|B)"` or `whatever[, "P(A|B)"]`.

Comment: read.csv() did replace the special characters with dots.  So hist(whatever$P.A.B.); works.  The quotes do not work which could be because the parentheses are no longer there.

Comment: I missed a key 'if' in my answer.  You would have to go back and rename the columns to make the second question apply.

Comment: you can use `check.names = FALSE` in your `read.csv` (or in `data.frame`) so that you can still have column names like P(A|B). The the quotes would work (however, I would recommend just using backticks all the time). But like @OtagoHarbour says, it doesn't work because R is checking the names of your columns and changing them to a format it likes

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
hist(whatever$"P(A|B)")
```

This should work fine.
Or use `whatever[,i]` where i is the number of column P(A|B)

Working example

```
whatever<-data.frame(test=rnorm(10))
colnames(whatever)<-"P(A|B)"
hist(whatever$"P(A|B)")
```

Comment: I tried hist(whatever$"P(A|B)"); but got the same result as before.  whatever[,i] works.  Thanks,

Comment: Maybe there also is a space in your column name.
Checkout colnames(whatever) to see how r interprets the column names.